# How to create multi section tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Hello am new to SO  i have this type of multidimensional array

`[["name1","name2"],["name3,"name4"],["name5","name6"]]`

and i want to create a UITableview with multiple sections

```
let tableView: UITableView = {
   let table = UITableView()

    return table
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(TableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tablecell")
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: tableView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: tableView)


}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("Groups are \(allGroups.count)")
    print(allGroups[0].count)
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return allGroups.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allGroups[section].count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell") as! TableCell
    for i in allGroups{
        cell.textLabel?.text = i[indexPath.row]
        for j in i{
            print(j)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Section \(section)"
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let vw = UIView()
    vw.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

    return vw
}

}
```

Here is what my code currently looks like but the the same data appears in every section

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code :-)

Comment: Am stuck i don't know how to access the array to use it for my delegates, like i can't count `numberOfRowsInSection` or `numberOfSections`

Comment: @Johnmayowa Edit your question with code that you are currently trying,

Comment: Questions has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113361/swift-populating-tableviews-with-multiple-sections-from-multidimensional-array

Comment: I added my code @Nathan

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you should be calling `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` in your `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: And why have you implemented both `titleForHeaderInSection` and `viewForHeaderInSection`? Only implement 0 or 1 of them, not both.

Comment: thank you! @rmaddy

Answer (score 2):

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return allGroups.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return allGroups[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell") as! TableCell

  cell.textLabel?.text = allGroups[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
  return cell
}
```

**Note**

You should not do this.

```
print(allGroups[0].count)
```

Maybe allGroups don't have any member, so allGroups[0] make crash with out of range issue.

Comment: How can i get number of section from the array i used?

Comment: Look at your example data.
 `[["name1","name2"],["name3,"name4"],["name5","name6"]]` . 
How many sections do you think ?

Comment: I think maybe OP wants help with how to determine the number of sections dynamically, given his sample dataset, which may grow or shrink.

Comment: three sections is there a way i can make the array into `["Group":["name1","name2"], "Group":["name3,"name4"],"Group":["name5","name6"]]`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want your data to in a variable.

```
var data = [["name1","name2"],["name3","name4"],["name5","name6"]]

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
```

To get the data from each section (this is untested)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return data[section].count

}
```

To adjust the code that you've provided, this should be all you need to do

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allGroups[section].count
}
```

Comment: How about numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: section and row starts at 0.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, but couldn't recall for sure. I'll remove the last bit.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to change this part of your code :

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell") as! TableCell
    for i in allGroups{
        cell.textLabel?.text = i[indexPath.row]
        for j in i{
            print(j)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

**With something like that**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell") as! TableCell

        let group = allGroups[indexPath.section] as! [String]
        let cellText = group[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellText

        return cell
    }
```